Freestyle contour lines don't cover my full model and obscures edges
I have a front facing orthographic view of a voxel model and I'm trying to give it an outline that only goes around the edges. But unless I tilt the model slightly the freestyle outline barely covers any of it. Additionally no matter what edge type I pick the outline will obscure my model when I don't want it to (setting thickness position to outside doesn't seem to help). I've tried working around this by putting a duplicate model without any outline in front of it, but that also seems to effect the outline behind it. Any help is appreciated.






If you can do this in the compositor instead of Freestyle, then that might be easiest.
The idea would be to use a Cryptomatte node to get a mask for the object and a "Dilate/Erode" node set to "Mode: Steps" to get a blocky expanded version of the mask.  Then "Alpha Over" the expanded mask with your fixed outline color and re-"Alpha Over" with the original mask to recomposite the object.
The compositor node setup would look something like this:

Here's my blend file .  It should be ready to render with F12.
